# How to get audio files from Private folder path in android

Tags: android, mediastore, android-music-player

I am trying to retrieve audio files from **Private Folder** for music player.

Below is my code -

```
    public ArrayList<MusicFiles> getAllAudio(Context context){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(MY_SORT_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String sortOrder = preferences.getString("sorting", "sortByName");
    ArrayList<String> duplicate = new ArrayList<>();
    albums.clear();
    ArrayList<MusicFiles> tempAudioList = new ArrayList<>();
    String order = null;
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    switch (sortOrder){
        case "sortByName":
            order = MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";
            break;
        case "sortByDate":
            order = MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED + " ASC";
            break;
        case "sortBySize":
            order = MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE + " DESC";
            break;
    }
    String[] projection = {
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID
    };
    String folder = getApplicationContext().getDir("Songs", MODE_PRIVATE).getAbsolutePath();
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " LIKE ? AND " + MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " NOT LIKE ? ";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
            "%" + folder + "%",
            "%" + folder + "/%/%"
    };

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, order);
    if(cursor != null){
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            String album = cursor.getString(0);
            String title = cursor.getString(1);
            String duration = cursor.getString(2);
            String path = cursor.getString(3);
            String artist = cursor.getString(4);
            String id = cursor.getString(5);
            MusicFiles musicFiles = new MusicFiles(path, title, artist, album, duration, id);
            //for checking
            Log.e("Path: " + path, "Album : " + album);
            tempAudioList.add(musicFiles);
            if(!duplicate.contains(album)){
                albums.add(musicFiles);
                duplicate.add(album);
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    return tempAudioList;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MediaStore` has no rights to access [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) for apps, and so `MediaStore` will not index them.

You can use ordinary filesystem APIs (e.g., `listFiles()` on `File`), to work with internal storage.

Note that you do not need `getApplicationContext()` in your code snippet above.

Comment: Hey thank you for attention Man...! How I can use `ordinary filesystem APIs`. I updated my code. How I can get other details like `album, title` etc from `ordinary filesystem APIs`.

Comment: @VikaSGuttE: AFAIK, you would use `MediaMetadataRetriever`: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever

Comment: do you have any example handy? Where I can get more idea so I can compare and implement.

Comment: @VikaSGuttE: "do you have any example handy?" -- no, sorry, as I have never needed to use `MediaMetadataRetriever`.